# Grouping by name and then adding up the number of another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an NFL dataset, and I'm trying to group by the player's name, and then add the amount of complete passes they managed for some analysis. However, I'm struggling to get by the first stage of even grouping them by the player. This is what I have so far:

```python
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from IPython.display import display

sql_sc = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read\
    .format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
    .options(header='true', inferschema='true')\
    .load('NFL Play by Play 2009-2018 (v5).csv')

df = df.withColumn("complete_pass", df["complete_pass"].cast(IntegerType()))
df = df.withColumn("pass_attempt", df["pass_attempt"].cast(IntegerType()))


test = df.groupBy("passer_player_name").sum("complete_pass")
display(test)
```

I expected to at least get a total of every player's completions, but I merely get this:

```python
DataFrame[passer_player_name: string, sum(complete_pass): bigint]
```

I understand this is probably a very basic problem, but I'm completely new to this!

Comment: try `test.show()`